# Why do I need to include the precompiled header in all the files in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers

If I don't include the stdafx even in an empty .cpp, I get this error

```
fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?
```

Why do I need to include it even in dummy files?

Comment: You don't, you can disable precompiled headers. You can even do that on a per-file basis.

Comment: Precompiled headers is just a feature of the compiler to speed up compilation when you have lots of or big header files. It can, as @Fanael says, be disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use them, then you must include them. But you can turn them off in the project properties.

However, the *recommended* way to use them is to "Force Include" the PCH from the *command line*, so that the file *itself* doesn't contain the PCH. That way the source file can be compatible with other systems.

Comment: But why do I need to include them in ALL the files? It doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @kunj2aan: because PCH is enabled for *all* the files. :-) You can actually disable them individually if you go to the Properties of a file and say Don't use PCH. But by default, the project settings apply to *all* the files, so that's why.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Yup, exactly. I think the problem (which also took me a while to understand when I had this question myself) is that PCH is not really a project property, but a source file property... but it's not *at all* obvious from the way it's set up, and it all looks like "magic" until you understand that `stdafx.cpp` is doing the real work, not `stdafx.h`.

Comment: Ah ok that makes a little more sense.. @Mhrdad : What is this magic in the stdafx.cpp : ) ?

Comment: @kunj2aan: It's the "Create precompiled headers" option when you go to the properties of stdafx.cpp, which is different from all other files'. I never knew it existed until I read it somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

You can disable precompiled headers per translation unit (in the properties for a given CPP file). You can probably do it per project too, if you're willing to explore the configuration GUI. Not all project types specify a PCH either; its just the standard Microsoft Way.

I've never encountered them outside of Microsoft land, so "in C++" is a little over general!

Comment: Other compilers like GCC also have a scheme for precompiled headers, but every implementation does it their own way. E.g. `g++ -o my_projects_pch.h.gch -x c++-header my_projects_pch.h` then `g++ -include my_projects_pch.h my_project.cpp` using -include will use a precompiled header if it exists.

Comment: Indeed, but happily they are a slightly eccentric option and as such I've never seen em used. Maybe I'm just lucky, though.