# Can force include be used with pre-compiled headers in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, precompiled-headers

If `/Yu` is set for an individual cpp file (i.e. not for an entire project) is it possible to set `/FI` to specify the header file to be included or must the header file be included with for example `#include "stdafx.h"` if `/Yu"stdafx.h"` is passed to CL?

All the following result in basically the same error...

With a header at `C:\path\to\stdafx.h` and `test.cpp` like so...

```
// Not including `stdafx.h`
void foo() {}
```

And any one of these to compile...

```
CL.exe /c /Yu"stdafx.h" /FI"C:\path\to\stdafx.h" test.cpp
CL.exe /c /Yu /FI"C:\path\to\stdafx.h" test.cpp
CL.exe /c /Yustdafx.h /FIC:\path\to\stdafx.h test.cpp
CL.exe /c /Yu /FIC:\path\to\stdafx.h test.cpp
```

`fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?`

It seems to me that it should be possible to use `/FI` to specify the precompiled header.

This answer seems to suggest it is even the preferred method
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052390/6225135

Comment: More answers that suggest it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11403418/15416. @VTT: `/FI` is described as an implicit `#include`

Comment: Might the problem be that `stdafx.h` is _not_ `C:\path\to\stdafx.h` ? IOW, the problem might be that VC++ does a string compare, rather than trying to decide whether both names would refer to the same file.

Comment: Yes that is it exactly, @MSalters
I had `/Yu"stdafx.h"` and `/FI"C:\full\path\to\stdafx.h"` which is a no-no
Even if they are equivalent they must be identical.

If you reply with that I will accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `stdafx.h` is not `C:\path\to\stdafx.h`. VC++ does a string compare. You'd need to add `C:\path\to\` to the include path, so you can use just  `/FI"stdafx.h"`

Comment: `/FI:stdafx.h` will look for `:stdafx.h` and won't work

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments I've managed to make it work properly. Turned out all I had to do is to supply *the same value* as for `/Yu`

```
/FI"stdafx.h"
```